# Sql -Data visible only once in rows rather than multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

In the below screenshot i have my output visible that way , but I do need it in the single line if they way many codes .

Comment: I cannot see any image.

Comment: No images please, use formatted text instead!

Comment: How do you know on duplicate `OriginalID` which one to take and which one(s) to leave? From what I can tell in your example data, the only column with different data is the `code` column.

Comment: You can use **DISTINCT** or some **GROUP BY** clause but obviously the output omits some data = they are not duplicates, the rows differ in **code**. How do you choose which one row you want in your output? Also, it would be helpful to see your query.

Comment: @IvankaEldé - edited the question with sample data

Comment: @jarlh edited the question with sample data

Comment: @Ryan Wilson edited the question with sample data

Comment: @kreme123 Thank you for editing your post, but that doesn't really answer my question. Say you have 3 records with the same `originalID` value, how do you determine which of the three you want to keep in your returned dataset?

Comment: i want all three by splitting code, code1, code2, to single line . like vertical method .. so that i can see original id , datein, dateout, cameout only once in the output by showing code, code1 , code 2 in vertical method

Comment: @kreme123 Then I think Gordon's answer below will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need aggregation:

```
select originalId, datein, dateout, camelid, min(code), min(code2), min(code3)
from t
group by originalId, datein, dateout, camelid
```